# Extract Date from UUID

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, uuid

I have a list of UUIDs and I'm trying to extract datetime from the code below I found online but it shows error.
Is there any other way or any changes in this code to extract it?

```
import uuid
import time_uuid

my_uuid = uuid.UUID('{7a3febe0-3fcc-3a28-bdab-c29438888d12}')
ts = time_uuid.TimeUUID(bytes=my_uuid.bytes).get_timestamp()
```

Error: No module named time_uuid

Expected: Datetime

Comment: you need to install time_uuid in order to use it, take a look at pip

Comment: check the docs: https://pypi.org/project/time-uuid/

Comment: @Netwave I installed it but there is still error in the code and it isn't giving me the desired output.Do you recommend any other way to extract date from UUIDs I have?

Comment: Show us how you have installed it and how you are running your code.

Comment: I installed package "time-uuid" and used "time_uuid" in program,
It worked for me